# Entity framework, getutcdate()

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Can I use the SQL-function getutcdate() from entity framework to set a date field in the database when saving an entity object?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can do this. The CLR function [`DateTime.UtcNow` is mapped to the canonical function `CurrentUtcDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx), which should translate, for SQL Server to `GETUTCDATE()` or similar.

```
var q = from e in Context.MyEntities
        select new
        {
            Entity = e,
            Time = DateTime.UtcNow
        };
```

Comment: Mapping to canonical functions only happens in LINQ to Entities queries. The question was not about using getUtcDate() when saving entities in the database and I am not sure how you can do that with LINQ queries. Can you please provide an example?

Comment: @FlorinDumitrescu, I understood the question. I added an example for you.

Comment: I accidentally slipped a "not" word in my comment above. What I meant was that the question is about saving data, not about retrieving it. Your provided example is about data retrieval. Can you adapt it for save?

Comment: @FlorinDumitrescu, if you want that behavior I'd put a default on the column or use a trigger.

Comment: How does this apply to inserts and updates.
I did a profile when using DateTime.UtcNow but it seemed to have used the actually applications date.

This makes sense as it is just accepting set values and not evaluating the expressions.

Comment: @Oliver: Inserts/Updates are totally different. They don't use LINQ and aren't mapped back to the server. Use a DB column default.

Comment: Yeah, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me. I adapted it a little to my needs like this: 

var dataServerUtc = myContext.Customers.Select( customerItem => DateTime.UtcNow ).FirstOrDefault(); 

My api server had a different time than the dataserver and I verified that it used the UTC time from data server.

Answer (score 1):

> when saving an entity object

I think what is asked here is: can I make EF insert/update a database row and set `GETUTCDATE()` *in the SQL statement*.

That's not the same as first getting a `DateTime` value from the database, setting the result in an object's property and then saving the object. That always stores a value that's "ages" before the actual current value at save time. Therefore, all the answers telling how to get `GETUTCDATE()` don't really answer the question.

In EF, to this day, it's impossible to generate insert statements containing `GETUTCDATE()`. In update statements it's only possible by [bulk updates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating?tabs=ef7#use-executeupdate-and-executedelete-when-relevant) introduced in EF-core 7

A statement like...

```cs
Products.ExecuteUpdate(p => p.SetProperty(x => x.IntroductionDate, DateTime.UtcNow));
```

...produces a SQL statement like this:

```sql
UPDATE [p]
SET [p].[IntroductionDate] = GETUTCDATE()
FROM [Products] AS [p]
```

I.e. it doesn't interpolate the C# `DateTime.UtcNow` value but translates it into SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you set the property on the entity to the UTC date before saving it?

Alternatively you could use stored procedures for insert/update/delete of your entities.  The stored procedure could perform this.

Comment: It isn't the same thing. Setting the property on the entity uses the app server's clock. Using `DateTime.UtcNow` uses the DB server's clock. The latter suggestion would work but is unnecessarily complicated for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retrieve the UTC DateTime from the SQL Server using Entity Framework, you can use the following code:

```
var databaseUtcDateTime = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<DateTime>("SELECT GETUTCDATE();").Single();
```

This will get you the current UTC DateTime from the SQL Server database.

It is useful when you cannot rely on the clock of the application host to be in sync with the SQL Server database.

I know this does not answer the question. But I found this question when I searched for how to get the UTC DateTime from the SQL Server using Entity Framework.

Answer (score -1):

You can't map directly to SQL built-in functions, but you can make EF calls to user-defined functions. Write a function that just returns `GETUTCDATE()`, then map to your user-defined function. I've done this before with `SOUNDEX()` (needed to select by soundex), and it worked out very nicely.

Comment: You *can* map to functions in EF 4, but in this case you don't need do, because this one is already mapped, even in EF 1.