# GetUTCDate with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I saw this question ([Entity framework, getutcdate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888004/entity-framework-getutcdate)):
"Can I use the SQL-function getutcdate() from entity framework to set a date field in the database when saving an entity object?"
with this answer from Craig Stuntz:
"Yes, you can do this. The CLR function DateTime.UtcNow is mapped to the canonical function CurrentUtcDateTime, which should translate, for SQL Server to GETUTCDATE() or similar."

Can somebody provide me a code snippet how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var q = from e in MyContext.SomeEntities
        select new 
        {
           Entity = e,
           Utc = DateTime.UtcNow
        };
```

I just tried this in LINQPad; it works.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted. I mean an entity with a DateTime property and then some that will generate something like this sql: UPDATE Table1 SET SomeProp=@p1, DateProp=GETUTCDATE() WHERE ....

Comment: Please feel free to ask the question you actually intended. I can't make heads or tails of your comment, and I believe I answered the question you *wrote.* In general, please do not expect anyone to put more effort into answering your questions than you put into writing them.